# How can we calculate the Jordan canonical form of a matrix given as direct sum of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> How can we calculate the Jordan canonical form of a matrix given as
>   direct sum of matrices?

Suppose $A= [J_4(1)]^2\oplus A_1 \oplus A_2$

where $A_1, A_2$ are some size $4$ matrices.

Then I want to know if we can find Jordan canonical form of all these matrices separately?

Comment: Well, you would want to calculate the Jordan forms for each of the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$. The Jordan form of $A$ will be the sum of the Jordan forms of the summands.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, so instead of dealing with size 12 matrix, I would be better off with dealing 3 size 4 matrices